# Javascript Function Checking

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a problem with JS function that I created: in my form I have 2 RadComboBoxes and a checkbox,Textbox the issue is I tried to create function that will check:  when if one item is picked form the 2 RadComboBox like: 1 item from one combobox and 1 item from the other combobox so it will go to the checkbox and check it and disable the textbox that is next to it. Thank You all.

http://srv1.jpg.co.il/6/5272a1e81373d.png

This is my Function in JS:

```
function checkLevelZone(sender, args) {
    var reVal = false
    var retValCB = false
    var l_level = $find("<%=ActOverviewLevel.ClientID %>").get_value();
    var l_levelInd = l_level.get_selectedIndex();
    var l_zone = $find("<%=ActOverViewZone.ClientID %>").get_value();
    var l_zoneInd = l_zone.get_selectedIndex();
    var l_CheckOffsite = $find("<%=cbOffSite.ClientID %>").set_checked(false);
    var l_txtOffsite = $find("<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>");
    if (!(l_levelInd == null) && !(l_zoneInd == null)) {
        retValRCB = true;
    }
    else {
        l_CheckOffsite.get_checked();
        l_txtOffsite.disable = true;
    }
    return reVal;
}
```

The ASP Code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ActOverViewZone" runat="server" Width="250px" TabIndex="10" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="checkLevelZone">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Exterior" Owner="ActOverViewZone" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Interior" Owner="ActOverViewZone" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ActOverviewLevel" runat="server" Width="250px" TabIndex="9" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="checkLevelZone">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem text="test1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem text="test2" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>

<asp:CheckBox ID="cbOffSite" runat="server"/>
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtOffSite" runat="server"> </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Comment: What you describe is not an issue.. it's a description of expected behavior.  What is your actual problem?

Comment: the function that I tried to create is not doing what I describe can someone help me with this please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script>
function checkLevelZone(sender, args) {
    var reVal = false;
    var retValCB = false;

    var l_level = $find("<%=ActOverviewLevel.ClientID %>");
    var l_levelInd = l_level.get_selectedIndex();

    var l_zone = $find("<%=ActOverViewZone.ClientID %>");
    var l_zoneInd = l_zone.get_selectedIndex();

    if (l_zoneInd > 0 && l_levelInd > 0) {
        $("#" + "<%=cbOffSite.ClientID %>").attr("checked", "checked");
        $("#" + "<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#" + "<%=cbOffSite.ClientID %>").removeAttr("checked");
        $("#" + "<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    return reVal;
}

</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.